# property initializers run before 'self' is available error

Tags: swift, xcode, self, xcode12, initializer

I was following a tutorial and wanted to add in a feature myself to a countdown timer. However, I get the error:

> Cannot use instance member 'timeRemaining' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

The code that seems to be creating the problem is here:

```
@State private var timeRemaining: CGFloat = defaultTimeRemaining

var i = timeRemaining
    func timeString(time: TimeInterval) -> String {
            let minute = Int(time) / 60 % 60
            let second = Int(time) % 60

            return String(format: "%02i:%02i",  minute, second)
        }
```

Sorry if this is a basic issue/ question. This is my first time using Xcode :)

Comment: initial value can't come from another property within the same `struct`/`class`. It has to be done within the initializer with a parameter or an actual value. So change `timeRemaining` and `defaultTimeRemaining` to actual numbers or do it in the initializer

Comment: `defaultTimeRemaining` is set to be a number earlier on like this: `let defaultTimeRemaining: CGFloat = 63`. Is this the issue?

Comment: Since the displayed time changes every second (which is done in the `defaultTimeRemaining` variable) I need the output of the function to also update

Comment: That is the issue. Try this change `@State private var timeRemaining: CGFloat = 0` and then in the `body` use `.onAppear(){timeRemaining = defaultTimeRemaining  i = timeRemaining}` at the end of the uppermost `View`

Comment: I'm most likely doing this wrong again but that just throws a bunch of errors at me

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) all of this is pretty basic stuff

Comment: Will do! Thanks for trying to help :)

Answer (score 0):

All properties in swift must be set before initialization.
Consider this code.

```
class MyObj {

     var value1 = 1
     var value2 = value1 + 1
     init(){}
}
```

init in swift requires both value1 and value2 to be set before it can return self

In this case it cannot because value2 requires a self.value1 to be set but value1 requires self to be set because its an instance var

consider this code

```
class myObj {

  var value1 = 1
  lazy var value2: Int = {
      value1 + 1
  }()
  init(){}
}
```

This is the one exception where we guarantee we will provide a value after init for an instance var.
We do this by setting it as lazy and provide a closure that happens the first time its accessed.

This is like force unwrapping a value but the init of the value is a block.

You can also use a class method or static method to get a value if you do not need an instance variable at time of setting.

```
var value2 = MyObj.onePlusOne()

class func onePlusOne() -> Int {
      1 + 1
}
```